# How delete vertex (node) on Polygon with Hole (Google Maps V3)

Tags: google-maps-api-3, polygon

I have taken this example (solution) from [Ian Grainger](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/9279742/4), but I added a Polygon with inner hole.

[This example](http://jsbin.com/jofefi/3) work fine for outer vertex path, but not for inner vertex path.

I need implement event Listener for internal and external node, because on fire event on internal vertex, delete external vertex. It doesn't work well.

Can someone provide some sample on how to solve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of your issues is polygon with a hole in it has multiple (in this case two) paths, and you aren't adding listeners for changes on both paths.  Below is a proof of concept, it isn't perfect, sometimes markers are orphaned, but should be a starting point.  Double click on the blue markers underneath the vertices to delete them (I couldn't get your "X" to reliably work).

[proof of concept fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/txa99fwj/16/)

[updated proof of concept with white markers](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/txa99fwj/19/)

**code snippet:**

```js
var G = google.maps;
var zoom = 8;
var centerPoint = new G.LatLng(37.286172, -121.80929);
var map;


$(function() {
  // create options object
  var myOptions = {
    center: centerPoint,
    zoom: zoom,
    mapTypeId: G.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  };

  // create map with options
  map = new G.Map($("#map_canvas")[0], myOptions);

  addPolygon(map);
});


function addPolygon(map) {
  var paths = [
    [new G.LatLng(37.686172, -122.20929),
      new G.LatLng(37.696172, -121.40929),
      new G.LatLng(36.706172, -121.40929),
      new G.LatLng(36.716172, -122.20929),
      new G.LatLng(37.686172, -122.20929)
    ],

    [new G.LatLng(37.486172, -122.00929),
      new G.LatLng(37.086172, -122.00929),
      new G.LatLng(37.086172, -121.60929),
      new G.LatLng(37.486172, -121.60929),
      new G.LatLng(37.486172, -122.00929)
    ]
  ];

  poly = new G.Polygon({
    clickable: false,
    paths: paths,
    map: map
  });
  polygonBinder(poly);
  poly.setEditable(true);
  G.event.addListener(poly.getPaths().getAt(0), 'insert_at', addClickMarker0);
  G.event.addListener(poly.getPaths().getAt(1), 'insert_at', addClickMarker1);
}

function polygonBinder(poly) {
  poly.binder0 = new MVCArrayBinder(poly.getPaths().getAt(0));
  poly.binder1 = new MVCArrayBinder(poly.getPaths().getAt(1));
  poly.markers = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < poly.getPaths().getLength(); i++) {
    poly.markers[i] = [];
    for (var j = 0; j < poly.getPaths().getAt(i).getLength(); j++) {
      var mark = new G.Marker({
        map: map,
        icon: {
          path: G.SymbolPath.CIRCLE,
          scale: 8,
          strokeWeight: 2,
          strokeColor: 'blue',
          fillColor: 'blue',
          fillOpacity: 1
        },
        draggable: true,
        title: "double click to delete [" + i + "," + j + "]",
        position: poly.getPaths().getAt(i).getAt(j)
      });
      poly.markers[i][j] = mark;
      mark.bindTo('position', poly["binder" + i], (j).toString());
      G.event.addListener(mark, "dblclick", deleteMark);
    }
  }

}

function addClickMarker0(index) {
  addClickMarker(index, 0);
}

function addClickMarker1(index) {
  addClickMarker(index, 1);
}

function deleteMark(evt) {
  var minDist = Number.MAX_VALUE;
  var minPathIdx = -1;
  var minIdx = -1;
  var i, j;
  for (i = 0; i < poly.getPaths().getLength(); i++) {
    for (j = 0; j < poly.getPaths().getAt(i).getLength(); j++) {
      var distance = G.geometry.spherical.computeDistanceBetween(evt.latLng, poly.getPaths().getAt(i).getAt(j));
      if (distance < minDist) {
        minDist = distance;
        minPathIdx = i;
        minIdx = j;
      }
      if (distance < 10) {
        document.getElementById('info').innerHTML = "deleted path=" + i + " idx=" + j + " dist<10 minDist=" + minDist + " meters";
        poly.getPaths().getAt(i).removeAt(j);
        break;
      }
    }
  }
  if ((i == poly.getPaths().getLength()) && (j == poly.getPaths(i - 1).getLength())) {
    poly.getPaths().getAt(minPathIdx).removeAt(minIdx);
    document.getElementById('info').innerHTML = "deleted path=" + minPathIdx + " idx=" + minIdx + " dist=" + minDist + " meters";
  }
  this.setMap(null);
}

function addClickMarker(index, pathIdx) {
  var path = this;
  // rebind binder
  for (var i = 0; i < poly.markers[pathIdx].length; i++) {
    poly.markers[pathIdx][i].setMap(null);
  }
  poly.markers[pathIdx] = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < poly.getPaths().getAt(pathIdx).getLength(); i++) {
    var mark = new G.Marker({
      map: map,
      icon: {
        path: G.SymbolPath.CIRCLE,
        scale: 8,
        strokeWeight: 2,
        strokeColor: 'blue',
        fillColor: 'blue',
        fillOpacity: 1
      },
      draggable: true,
      title: "double click to delete [" + pathIdx + "," + i + "]",
      position: poly.getPaths().getAt(pathIdx).getAt(i)
    });
    poly.markers[pathIdx][i] = mark;
    mark.bindTo('position', poly["binder" + pathIdx], (i).toString());
    G.event.addListener(mark, "dblclick", deleteMark);
  }
}

function MVCArrayBinder(mvcArray) {
  this.array_ = mvcArray;
}
MVCArrayBinder.prototype = new google.maps.MVCObject();
MVCArrayBinder.prototype.get = function(key) {
  if (!isNaN(parseInt(key))) {
    return this.array_.getAt(parseInt(key));
  } else {
    this.array_.get(key);
  }
}
MVCArrayBinder.prototype.set = function(key, val) {
  if (!isNaN(parseInt(key))) {
    this.array_.setAt(parseInt(key), val);
  } else {
    this.array_.set(key, val);
  }
}
```

```css
html,
body,
#map_canvas {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=drawing,geometry"></script>
<div id="info"></div>
<div id="map_canvas" style="width:100%; height:100%"></div>
```

Comment: So many many many thanks geocodezip! I didn't had time this week to look at your solution. Like always: much appreciated !!!