# Add Listener to multi path polygon points

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have a multi path polygon and I want to add a 'rightclick' listener to remove the point from the polygon (so from the outer polygon or from the hole - inner polygon).

I have tried passing the polygon object to the listener

```
google.maps.event.addListener(polygon, 'rightclick', function (event) {
```

This adds a listener to the points but I'm not sure its correct as it does not distinguish point 2 from the outer polygon or the inner polygon.

Any help would be very appreciated

Comment: The event has a `latLng` associated with it - `event.latLng` - use that.

Comment: Thanks Adam. Not sure how I would use 'event.latLng' in the context of using the removeAt method if that method only accepts a number

Comment: I found a solution to the problem I was having in this link ----  [how delete vertex node on polygon with hole google maps v3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35787756/how-delete-vertex-node-on-polygon-with-hole-google-maps-v3)